# Copying values from various Workbooks and Worksheets into other Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, do-while

I'm trying to loop through worksheets from various workbooks and copy values (starting with a single cell). I need to paste the copied values into a worksheet in a new workbook one below another in the first row.

I work with three workbooks. Each workbooks has two sheets.

I loop through all worksheets in the three workbooks.

Following problem occurs: only the values from the second sheets are copied into the master file.

```
Sub RunOnAllFilesInFolder()

    Dim folderName As String, eApp As Excel.Application, fileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, currWs As Worksheet, currWb As Workbook
    Dim fDialog As Object: Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    Set currWb = ActiveWorkbook: Set currWs = ActiveSheet
    Dim ID As String
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    counter = 2
    fDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
    fDialog.InitialFileName = currWb.Path

    If fDialog.Show = -1 Then
        folderName = fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If

    Set eApp = New Excel.Application: eApp.Visible = False
    Set eApp2 = New Excel.Application: eApp.Visible = False
    Set wb2 = eApp2.Workbooks.Add

    fileName = Dir(folderName & "\*.xls")

    Do While fileName <> ""

        Application.StatusBar = "Processing " & folderName & "\" & fileName
        Set wb = eApp.Workbooks.Open(folderName & "\" & fileName)

        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            ws.Range("A1").Copy
        Next ws

        wb2.Worksheets(1).Cells(counter, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Debug.Print "Processed" & folderName & "\" & fileName
        fileName = Dir()
        counter = counter + 1

    Loop

    wb2.SaveAs ("Results.xlsx")
    eApp.Quit
    Set eApp = Nothing
    eApp2.Quit
    Set eApp2 = Nothing

    Application.StatusBar = ""
    MsgBox "Completed executing Macro"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is with your worksheet Looping. You are copying the content from a worksheet but pasting the value after the worksheet loop. That's why you are getting values from only one sheet. The below code should work for you.

```
Sub RunOnAllFilesInFolder()

        Dim folderName As String, eApp As Excel.Application, fileName As String
        Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, currWs As Worksheet, currWb As Workbook
        Dim fDialog As Object: Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        Set currWb = ActiveWorkbook: Set currWs = ActiveSheet
        Dim ID As String
        Dim counter As Integer
        Dim i As Integer

        counter = 2
        fDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
        fDialog.InitialFileName = currWb.Path

        If fDialog.Show = -1 Then
            folderName = fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
        End If

        Set eApp = New Excel.Application: eApp.Visible = False
        Set eApp2 = New Excel.Application: eApp.Visible = False
        Set wb2 = eApp2.Workbooks.Add

        fileName = Dir(folderName & "\*.xls")

        Do While fileName <> ""

            Application.StatusBar = "Processing " & folderName & "\" & fileName
            Set wb = eApp.Workbooks.Open(folderName & "\" & fileName)

            For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
                ws.Range("A1").Copy
                wb2.Worksheets(1).Cells(counter, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                counter = counter + 1
            Next ws

            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Debug.Print "Processed" & folderName & "\" & fileName
            fileName = Dir()
        Loop

        wb2.SaveAs ("Results.xlsx")
        eApp.Quit
        Set eApp = Nothing
        eApp2.Quit
        Set eApp2 = Nothing
        Application.StatusBar = ""
        MsgBox "Completed executing Macro"
    End Sub
```